# Inject dependencies into grunt serve index file

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

so i'm using bower for my packages and grunt serve is as far as i've gone with grunt, what i want to know is, just to save me the time.

how do i get grunt/bower to include what i need either from the command line (would be best for workflow) or using the .json file in the initial index.html file?

so in this case i've ran,

```
yo webapp(or mobile)
bower install topcoat --save
bower install jplayer --save
bower update
grunt serve
```

heres my json file

```
{
  "name": "imtoolbox",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "topcoat": "~0.8.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.4",
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "jplayer": "~2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

my head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:css styles/vendor/topcoat/css/topcoat-mobile-light.min.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/topcoat/css/topcoat-mobile-light.min.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

my scripts

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js scripts/async-local-storage.js -->
        <script src="scripts/async.localStorage.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/async.localStorage.examples.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js scripts/fullscreensnippet.js -->
        <script src="scripts/fullscreensnippet.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js scripts/fastclick.js -->
        <script src="scripts/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/fastclick.example.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

any help on this would be great it seams theres a lot of different answers online and having something that works would be sweet!

Comment: In your `Gruntfile.js` do you have a section that configures bower? Is https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install installed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing bower's wiring

```
<!-- build:js scripts/myscripts.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```